# Check if any cells in one column fall between cells in different columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel

So I'm trying to figure out if any call for service happens during the time frame of another call.

The information is set up below like this:

```
| |[A]|[B]|[C]|
|:---|:---|:---|:---|
|1|"Call Time"|"En route"|"in service"| 
|2|08:30|08:31|09:55 
|3|10:04|10:04|11:25
|4|10:28|10:30|11:15 
|5|12:22|12:23|13:05 
|6|12:45|12:49|13:40
```

So obviously A4 falls between B3,C3, and A6 falls between B5,C5.
I've used the formula

```
=arrayformula(isbetween(a2:a6, b2:b6, c2:c6,))
```

and it will only check if the A value of the specific row is between the B and C values of the same row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: isbetween]

Try this formula:

```
=isbetween(A3:A6,B2:B5,C2:C5)
```

you could conditional format column A (A3:A1000)  with custom formula:

```
=and(A3<>"",isbetween(A3,B2,C2))
```

Comment: Hey that worked perfectly! Thank you so much!